# nicematrix: controlling column spaces

Tags: amsmath, nicematrix

I have a code and that works well.

But as a question of detail, I asked myself: 
I want a very small distance from the last annotation column to the right parenthesis.

Is it in the sense of `nicematrix.sty` to use `\hspace{-0.5ex}` here, 
in `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hspace{-0.5ex}$\ttfamily\footnotesize}l<{$}}`?

Or does `nicematrix.sty` know a corresponding key for the this column spacing?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\NoOfVariables{3}%  Input number of variables here! %%%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hspace{-0.5ex}$\ttfamily\footnotesize}l<{$}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{LGS}{}
{%
    \let \{ \lgroup 
    \let \} \rgroup
\begin{NiceArray}{\{ *{\NoOfVariables}{r} |  r  \} L}}%
{\end{NiceArray}}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand\error{\faWarning}
\newcommand\mal{\ensuremath{\cdot}{}}
\newcommand\step{\hspace{1em}\ensuremath{\rightarrow}\hspace{1em}}

\begin{document}
\noindent$\begin{LGS}
1 &  2 &  -1 &  1 &  {}  \\
0 &  1 &   1 &  2 &  {}  \\
2 &  1 &   1 &  1 &  {-2\mal I}  \\
3 &  2 &   1 &  1 &  {-3\mal I}  \\
\end{LGS}
\step
\begin{LGS}
1 &  2 &  -1 &  1  &  {}  \\
0 &  1 &   1 &  2  &  {}  \\
0 & -3 &   3 & -1  &  {}  \\
0 & -4 &   4 & -2  &  {:2}  \\
\end{LGS}
\step \dots \step
\begin{LGS}
1 &  0 &  -3  &  -3  &  {}  \\
0 &  1 &   1  &   2  &  {}  \\
0 &  0 &   6  &   5  &  {}  \\
0 &  0 &   0  &   -1  &  {\error}  \\
\end{LGS}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that your solution is a good solution. However, since the environments of `nicematrix` are constructed upon the standard environment `{array}` (in the version defined in the classical package `array`, which is loaded by `nicematrix`), I suggest a solution in the spirit of `{array}`.

In an `{array}`, an `\hspace{2\arraycolsep}` is inserted between two consecutive columns. By using the special construction `@{...}` in the preamble of the array, you can replace these elements by whatever you want, for instance an instruction `\hspace{...}` adjusted.

That's what I have done in the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\ttfamily\footnotesize}l<{$}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{LGS}{}
{%
    \let \{ \lgroup 
    \let \} \rgroup
\begin{NiceArray}{\{ r r r  |  r \} @{\hspace{1.8ex}} L}}% Input number of columns! %%%
{\end{NiceArray}}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand\error{\faWarning}
\newcommand\mal{\ensuremath{\cdot}{}}
\newcommand\step{\hspace{1em}\ensuremath{\rightarrow}\hspace{1em}}

\begin{document}
\noindent$\begin{LGS}
1 &  2 &  -1 &  1 &  {}  \\
0 &  1 &   1 &  2 &  {}  \\
2 &  1 &   1 &  1 &  {-2\mal I}  \\
3 &  2 &   1 &  1 &  {-3\mal I}  \\
\end{LGS}
\step
\begin{LGS}
1 &  2 &  -1 &  1  &  {}  \\
0 &  1 &   1 &  2  &  {}  \\
0 & -3 &   3 & -1  &  {}  \\
0 & -4 &   4 & -2  &  {:2}  \\
\end{LGS}
\step \dots \step
\begin{LGS}
1 &  0 &  -3  &  -3  &  {}  \\
0 &  1 &   1  &   2  &  {}  \\
0 &  0 &   6  &   5  &  {}  \\
0 &  0 &   0  &   -1  &  {\error}  \\
\end{LGS}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]